# Bring MessageBox to Foreground

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to prompt the user with a `wx.MessageBox` like so, but I am facing a few issues doing that:

```
response = wx.MessageBox(MESSAGE, document, wx.YES_NO | wx.STAY_ON_TOP) # prompt the user
```

For some reason, the dialog box refuses to stay on top regardless of the flag I have passed to do that. Is there a fool proof method of spawning a dialog box at the top of all running foreground applications?

Comment: This works for me on Windows 7 with wxPython 3.0.2 and Python 2.7. What are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1 and the rest are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I read somewhere that `wx.STAY_ON_TOP` when used with a `dialog` only works with MSW. Be that as it may you can get around the problem by assigning `STAY_ON_TOP` to `self`

EDIT:
Rather than dismissing it out of hand and marking it as not useful, try the following. Only Clicking on the `Question` button stays on top, the rest act as normal (on Linux anyway)

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):    
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)
        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Info')
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Error')
        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Question')
        btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label='Alert')
        sizer.AddMany([btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4])
        hbox.Add(sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 15)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowMessage1)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowMessage2)
        btn3.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowMessage3)
        btn4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ShowMessage4)
        self.SetSize((300, 200))
        self.SetTitle('Messages')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)
#        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
    def ShowMessage1(self, event):
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Download completed', 'Info', wx.OK)
        dial.ShowModal()

    def ShowMessage2(self, event):
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Error loading file', 'Error', 
            wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        dial.ShowModal()

    def ShowMessage3(self, event):
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Are you sure to quit?', 'Question', 
            wx.YES_NO | wx.NO_DEFAULT | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
        dial.ShowModal()
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)

    def ShowMessage4(self, event):
        dial = wx.MessageDialog(None, 'Unallowed operation', 'Exclamation', 
            wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
        dial.ShowModal()

def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```